# Sencha grid: hidden column and combobox

Tags: extjs4, extjs

First a small portion of the code:

```
{                text: 'TipoVisitaID',
            hidden: true,
            dataIndex: 'TipoVisitaID',
            itemId: 'TipoVisitaID'
        }, {
            text: 'TIPO VISITA',
            flex: 1,
            sortable: true,
            align: 'right',
            dataIndex: 'TipoVisita',
            editor: {
                xtype: 'combo',
                allowBlank: true,
                store: allTiposVisita,
                valueField: 'Id',
                name: 'TiposVisitaCombo',
                itemId: 'TiposVisitaCombo',
                tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
                                    '<tpl for=".">',
                                        '<div class="x-boundlist-item">{Designacao}</div>',
                                    '</tpl>'),
                displayTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate', '<tpl for=".">', '{Designacao}', '</tpl>')
            }
        },
```

What i would like to achivie is this.

When editing the row i would like that the selected value for the combo to be the value in the hidden field.

Is this even possible??

I've tried doing this: (on the combo)

```
value: Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#TipoVisitaID")[0] == null ? '' : Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#TipoVisitaID")[0].value
```

but it doesn't work...

Comment: When do you want to do this? Use the method `getValue()` instead of `value`.

Comment: getValue() also doesn't work... I want when the inline edit begins the combobox has a pre-selected value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem.

```
{
            text: 'TIPO VISITA',
            flex: 1,
            sortable: true,
            align: 'right',
            dataIndex: 'TipoVisitaID',
            renderer: function (loader, response, active) {
                return active.raw.TipoVisita;
            },
            editor: {
                xtype: 'combo',
                allowBlank: true,
                store: allTiposVisita,
                valueField: 'Id',
                name: 'TiposVisitaCombo',
                itemId: 'TiposVisitaCombo',
                tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
                                    '<tpl for=".">',
                                        '<div class="x-boundlist-item">{Designacao}</div>',
                                    '</tpl>'),
                displayTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate', '<tpl for=".">', '{Designacao}', '</tpl>')
            }
        },
```

First i changed the dataIndex to the ID. But now the user would see the ID instead of the data, that's why i use the renderer so that the user sees the data and not the ID.

I then added the listener 'beforeedit' to the grid in which i did this:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#TiposVisitaCombo")[0].setValue(e.record.raw.TipoVisitaID);
```

Thus setting the value of the combo (making it the preselected one) with the ID.

Answer (score 0):

Add a event listener to edit event on the grid and update data in your hidden field from there. This event will fire after edit is complete.

```
grid.on('edit', function (editor, e){ 
     e.record.set('TipoVisitaID', e.value);
}
```

Comment: This will only work when the user clicks directly on the cell... I want the pre-selected value to "appear" independently of the cell clicked...

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
var theHidden = Ext.getCmp('TipoVisitaID');
var theCombo = Ext.getCmp('TiposVisitaCombo'); =
theCombo.on('change', function(combo, newValue, oldValue, e){
  theHidden.setValue(newValue);
});
```

Comment: Ext.getCmp('#TipoVisitaID') returns undefined.                            Also what i want would be like theCombo.setValue(theHidden) so that when combo is render the hidden value would be the preselected one.

Comment: Oops my mistake, I barely use getCmp and I didn't test the code. You can use your code I guess